# How do I check for syntax errors in my Apache web server configuration

Tags: linux, apache2, apache

How do I check for syntax errors in the configuration of my apache server without having to restart or reload the rules? This would be preferably done from the terminal/command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If syntax is ok:

`sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Will reply with:

`Syntax OK`

Answer (score 9):

You can use this as well if you don't have httpd.

```
apachectl configtest
```

Answer (score 6):

On linux, you use

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -t
```

On windows, you would use the equivalent command to the httpd.exe file